# Can this SQL Query for Grouping Multiple Columns and Date be Improved in any way?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to refresh my very rusty SQL skills.

I have a table with device logs, collected every 5 minutes. I'm interested in counting the number of times a device is either 'connected' or 'disconnected' per device, per day.

```csv
deviceId,  status,  tag,   timestamp
A,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:25:02Z
B,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:25:02Z
C,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:25:02Z
D,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:25:02Z
E,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:25:02Z
A,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:30:02Z
B,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:30:02Z
C,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:30:02Z
D,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:30:02Z
E,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:30:02Z
A,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:35:02Z
B,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:35:02Z
C,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:35:02Z
D,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:35:02Z
E,  Disconnected, connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:35:02Z
A,  Connected,    connectivity,  2022-10-27T09:48:10Z
```

I came up with the following SQL, since it's been a while, I was wondering if anyone has some feedback or alternative ideas.

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Connected' THEN 1 END) connectedCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Disconnected' THEN 1 END) disconnectedCount, deviceId, 
    FORMAT(CAST(timestamp AS DATE), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date
FROM Reporting
WHERE tag = 'connectivity'
GROUP BY deviceId, FORMAT(CAST(timestamp AS DATE), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY date, deviceId
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thanks. Do you have a suggestion for a better title?

Comment: What's the DBMS you're currently using?